# Logging Exceptions in Laravel Properly

Tags: php, laravel, logging

I'm looking for a convenient way to log exceptions in Laravel. When I deploy my application into the "Production" environment, I want to record ***every*** exception thrown by the application in a table called "Error Logs" in the database. This table will contain columns indicating which method, line and class the exception was thrown from. In addition, I want to send an email to a specific address whenever a new record is added to this table, indicating that a new error has occurred. I tried creating a global function and using it in try-catch blocks, but it didn't seem like a very effective way to log every possible exception being thrown.

Comment: Without the full stack trace, seems pointless. Why not utilise the `storage/log/laravel.log` file and use `awk` or `grep` magic to find things

Comment: There is a whole chapter in the documentation about [reporting exceptions](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/errors#reporting-exceptions). I use to have a stack channel for different environments and projects that would notify me anything of what’s going on. Many services like nginx can do the same, most of them work without the hassle of implementing something completely revolutionary